# Redirecting output to a text file in C from the command line

Tags: c, shell, unix, command

Im implementing a shell in c, and im having a hard time redirecting the output of a command to a file.
When i send the output to a file, it seems to work but the file does not open and when i run a ls -l it shows me the following:

```
---------x   1 warp  staff   441 Nov  4 20:15 output.txt
```

This is some part of my code

```
pid = fork();
if(pid == 0) 
{ /* child process */

    if(redirFlag)
    {
        int fdRedir = open(redirectName, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT );
        if( fdRedir < 0){
            perror("Can't Open");
            exit(1);
        }

        if(dup2(fdRedir, STDOUT_FILENO) == -1){
            perror("dup2 failed");
            exit(1);
        }


    } 
    execvp(supplement[0], supplement);
    /* return only when exec fails */
    perror("exec failed");
    exit(-1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The prototype of `open` is :

```
#include <fcntl.h>  
int open(const char *path, int oflag, ...);
```

When the file is created, you should give the file mode.

```
int open(const char *path, int oflags, mode_t mode);
```

In your code, the file is opened with flag `O_CREAT` but the file mode is not given. So you don't have the permission to operate on it. Try to indicate the file permission when create the new file:

```
int fdRedir = open(redirectName, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0644);
```

Comment: +1: Strictly, the prototype of [`open()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html)
 is `int open(const char *path, int oflag, ...);`, but the net result is pretty much as you say: if you specify `O_CREAT`, you need to specify the third argument too.  Without that, it is indeterminate what value is treated as the mode; from the result, it appears that the answer is `1`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks for giving the more strict prototype, I updated the answer.